# Iterating over an array of directories and performing mkdir on each one in a special way

Tags: perl

I have an array of directories. I want to iterate over the array and perform `mkdir` on it:

```
foreach my $dir (@dirs) {
    print $fh "mkdir -p $dir\n";
}
```

I want to reduce the amount of chars in the file. So I want to use the special case of `mkdir` which allows to use `{name,name,name}`  and it will create all of them. So for example, instead of:

```
mkdir -p /a/b/c/e/f
mkdir -p /a/b/c/e/g
mkdir -p /a/b/c/e/h
```

It will do:

```
mkdir -p /a/b/c/e/{f,g,h}
```

The dirs are already in their canonical mode so `realpath` is not required here.

What would be the best way to iterate over the array `@dirs` and do this? I think I need to use `dirname` on each one and then collect every "collection" and then do mkdir on it. But what is the best way to do it?

Comment: Why not just create the directories in the perl script instead of writing out what looks like a bash script to do it?

Comment: @Shawn I create a bash script "on the fly". That is the purpose of the Perl script.

Comment: It might be possible to create a finite state automaton based on the input dirs, then minimize it to get the glob expression. Seems like a lot of work. Why do you need it? What's the problem with generating the whole list in the shell script?

Comment: Again, why not just do it all at once, in perl? Using [`mkpath` from `Path::Tiny`](https://metacpan.org/pod/Path::Tiny#mkpath) or [`make_path` from `File::Path`](https://metacpan.org/pod/File::Path#make_path\(-$dir1,-$dir2,-....-\)) makes it trivial.

Comment: Grouping sibling dirs with the same immediate parent could do the job. Giving sample of dirs would be helpful.

Comment: hi guys, thank you for the comments! I don't want to use Perl modules to perform the operations because I create the bash script on the fly. This script is being published for users to use. And unfortunately the script have to be in bash. I didn't actually think that would be such trouble.

Comment: See also [this discussion on PerlMonks](https://www.perlmonks.org/?node_id=11131998).

Answer (score 3):

It can be done by two loops:

```
use strict;

# your Filehandle
my $fh;
my @dirs = qw" /a/b/c/e/f
               /a/b/c/e/g
               /a/b/c/e/h ";

# use a hash for temporary hold the dirs per path
my %split_dirs;

for (@dirs) {
    # Split the current path into the path (..../) and the dir behind.
    my ($current_path, $current_dir) = /^(.*\/)(.*)$/;
    # if there where already a dir for this path, add this one and go
    # to the next iteration else there would be created a new one.
    push(@{$split_dirs{$current_path}}, $current_dir);
}

# Now you can join the values per path and print out.
print $fh "mkdir -p $_\{" .
          join(",", @{$split_dirs{$_}}) .
          "\}\n"
    for (keys %split_dirs);
```

Or a little more compact:

```
# ...

my %split_dirs;

/^(.*\/)(.*)$/,
    push(@{$split_dirs{$1}}, $2)
    for (@dirs);

print $fh "mkdir -p $_\{" .
          join(",", @{$split_dirs{$_}}) .
          "\}\n"
    for (keys %split_dirs);
```

Output

```txt
mkdir -p /a/b/c/e/{f,g,h}
```

Comment: `/^(.*/)(.*)$/` or `fileparse` would be better that your regex that assumes the filename will be 1 character only. The whole `next if defined...` can be removed since Perl performs autovivification. Finally, your solution prints curly brackets if there is a single element inside, which could easily be avoided.

Comment: @Dada - cause of the regex: cruel error... and yes `if defined ...` can remoded! Sure!

Answer (score 2):

This is what [`Compress::BraceExpansion`](https://metacpan.org/pod/Compress::BraceExpansion) was designed for:

> My initial motivation to write this module was to compress the number
> of characters that are necessary to display a list of server names,
> e.g. to send in the subject of a text message to a pager/mobile phone.
> If I start with a long list of servers that follow a standard naming
> convention, e.g.:
>
> ```
> app-dc-srv01 app-dc-srv02 app-dc-srv03 app-dc-srv04 app-dc-srv05
> app-dc-srv06 app-dc-srv07 app-dc-srv08 app-dc-srv09 app-dc-srv10
> ```
>
> After running through this module, they can be displayed much more
> efficiently on a pager as:
>
> ```
> app-dc-srv{0{1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9},10}
> ```
>
> The algorithm can also be useful for directories:
>
> ```
> /usr/local/{bin,etc,lib,man,sbin}
> ```

Be aware of the present limitations though:

> The current algorithm is pretty ugly, and will only compress strings that start and/or end with similar text. I've been working on a new algorithm that uses a weighted trie.